# Query: Assigning error datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I want to assign `'1392-04-31'` using this code:

```
DECLARE @t DATETIME
SET @t = '92-04-31'
```

I see this error:

`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Any one know why?

Comment: How do you think this should implicitly map '92-04-31' -> '1392-04-31'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:
use datetime2!

```
DECLARE @t datetime2
SET @t = '1392-04-30'
```

Because you can't use datetime:
The minimum date stored in datetime is January 1, 1753. So 1392 is not storeable.

April has 30 days.

Using formatted date with datetime:

Second, when you write a date in Sql Server, the format I prefer is {d 'YYYY-MM-DD'}, so in your case becomes:

```
DECLARE @t DATETIME
SET @t = {d '1992-04-30'}
```

To complete this discussion, if you want use hh mm ss so you must use this format: {ts 'yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm'}

```
DECLARE @t DATETIME
SET @t = {ts '1992-04-30 23:59:59.123'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The date you are trying to set is probably invalid.

Also there are several ways of representing dates in SQL as a string, depending on Language, Dateformat and other setting. Typically the safest way to do this is to use the 'YYYYMMDD' format.

The article below will also answer the question : Why is 1753 the earliest date for datetime?

You should read this if you would like some detailed information:

http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
declare @t DATETIME
set @t = '1992-04-30 10:54:30'
```

Comment: you can't insert Persian dateTime into SQL.
you have to convert it to Julian.
when you want to insert 92-04-31 into SQL, it means you are inserting 1992-04-31 and we have 30 days in April and then you got error.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, April only has 30 days.  I'm not going to take the time to look up historically whether that was the case in 1392, but either way I'm pretty sure the date 4/31/1392 is invalid for a SQL Server DATETIME.

Also, you should use the full year in the format '01-01-2013'.

Try the following and you'll get the output Jan  1 2013 12:00AM.

```
declare @t DATETIME
set @t = '01-01-2013'
PRINT @t
```

The above should work for any valid date.

Comment: Your answer does not make it clear whether the month or the day comes first. Also this date format will fail in another lanugage. For example: SET LANGUAGE British
go
declare @t DATETIME
set @t = '02-20-2013'
PRINT @t

Comment: Your answer may be correct in the particular example that you are giving, but is actually misleading in leading people to believe that MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY is a safe format to use in SQL. If you read the article in the link I provided below, you will not make this mistake next time. Don't take this personally but we are all here to learn, even those who answer questions.